# Dynamically add objects to UITableView cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

[image]![enter image description here][2]I have a table view,in which I am using my custom cell that contains user's profile picture,status label, time stamp label, username label, no of comments label and a comment button. 
When no of comments i.e"4 comments" is tapped, I ha ve to show comments in the corresponding cell along with username, user profile picture etc below the original post.
 How do I dynamically add these objects into cell when the app is running? or there is some else solution please tell. table for 2 posts is shown in right of image. Tapping no of comments left of the image should be shown.
 Here is the code for table cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    TableCell *cell = (TableCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray* topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableCell" owner:self   options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = (TableCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    User *user = [postTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"pic:%@",user.profilePictureURL);
    cell.profilePicture.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar.png"];
    cell.profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = cell.profilePicture.frame.size.height /2;
    cell.profilePicture.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cell.profilePicture.layer.borderWidth = 0;

    cell.userName.text = user.name;
    cell.status.text = user.status;
    cell.dateForStatus.text = user.datePosted;
    [cell.countComments setTitle:user.countOfComments forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    [cell.contentView.layer setBorderWidth:6.0f];
    [cell.contentView.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:233/255.0 green:236/255.0 blue:233/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor];
    cell.commentButton.tag=indexPath.row;
    [cell.commentButton addTarget:self action:@selector(commentButtonPressAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return cell;
    ![enter image description here][3]}
```

Comment: see this link to know about custom cell http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/ It will help you.

Comment: Use `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying to expand the cell.

You can call these few lines to update the cell, including the height.

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

So just set a flag to show comments in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
//AFTER_YOUR_SETTING
if(showComment){
    [cell loadCommentMethod];
}
```

And also, in heightForRowAtIndexPath

```
if(showComment){
    return [CellClass publicMethodForCalHeight:dataAtIndexPath];
} else {
    return kDefaultCellHeight;
}
```

Comment: this one looks closer,

Comment: how do i get indexpath?? I have indexpath.row

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it works but you can try this. Override `touchesBegan:` on your cell:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
     CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];    
     CGRect rect = [noComments frame];

     if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point))
     {
        UILabel *label = ... // the label you need to add.
       [self addSubview:label];
     }
}
```

Comment: This one is a little fine. Problem is, it adds object when whole cell is tapped from any where in the cell.

Comment: @AliHassan you need to add objects when a certain area in the cell is tapped?

Comment: yup,when no of comments is tapped

Answer (score 1):

Change your button action method:

```
- (void)onButtonTaped:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = sender;
    UILabel *newLabel = [ [ UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake (0, 100, 200, 50)];
    newLabel.text = @"Your new text here";
    [button.superview addSubview:newLabel];
}
```

But label will be visible only until cell will be visible on screen. When cell will be recreated label will be deleted. To keep label you still need to change

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: This method is called when the tableview is loaded first time, not when label inside the table cell is tapped.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the method `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` of the `UITableView`. You can refer [this link](http://adampreble.net/blog/2009/09/editing-a-uitableview-the-animated-insert-row/) for a tutorial. Also refer the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/insertRowsAtIndexPaths%3awithRowAnimation%3a)

Comment: This will add new cell. I need to objects in the cell. is this possible?

Comment: Actually I would suggest, instead of adding objects (I'm not sure what objects you are referring to) add cells itself. Create a new custom cell and insert cells as many comments you have. You can also provide decent animation during the show/hide comment process which are readily available in the form of UITableViewRowAnimations